# How can you show for an infinite set of basis that it spans the vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

So for a finite set of vectors it is important to show that it spans the set and that the vectors are linearly dependent.

But for a vector space with infinite dimensions, how can you show that a set of vectors (if they are orthogonal) also span the set? Can an infinite set of vectors that are mutually orthogonal NOT span the set? That seems weird, because you could make a bijection between the basis vectors and dimensions (I think I worded that not correctly, I hope someone can correct me on that)

Comment: $\{x\mapsto e^{inx}:n=1,3,\dots\}$

Comment: Well, if you have an infinite basis of mutually orthogonal vectors, just remove one.

Comment: In the finite-dimensional case, all linearly independent sets of the right size are spanning sets (and likewise all spanning sets of the right size are linearly independent); this is *not* true in the infinite-dimensional case.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen Doesn't that only apply to separable Hilbert spaces?

Answer (score -1):

The way to show that a set is a basis is the same for both finite- and infinite-dimensional vector spaces:

1. Show that the set spans the space by considering an arbitrary vector $\mathbf{v} \in V$ and expressing it as a (finite) linear combination of vectors from the set.
2. Show that the set is linearly independent by demonstrating that any finite linear combination of its elements that gives the zero vector must have all of its coefficients equal to zero.

For example, to show that $\{1, x, x^2, \ldots\}$ spans $\mathbb{R}[x]$, the set of polynomials with real coefficients, you consider an arbitrary polynomial $p(x) = a_0 + a_1 x + \ldots + a_n x^n$ and it's pretty obviously a linear combination of $\{1, x, \ldots, x_n\}$ which is a finite subset of the basis. Then to show the linear independence, you just need to prove that $a_0 + a_1 x + \ldots + a_n x^n \equiv 0$ is equivalent to $a_0 = a_1 = \ldots = a_n = 0$, which you can show via induction.

If a set *isn't* a basis, then that involves either showing that it doesn't span the vector space - i.e. you prove that there's a vector $\mathbf{v} \in V$ that can't be written as a linear combination of its elements - or it isn't linearly independent - i.e. you prove that one of its elements can be written as a linear combination of other elements. For example, if we take $1$ out of the above basis of $\mathbb{R}[x]$, then you can prove that there's no way to write the constant polynomial $p(x) = 1$ as a linear combination of the remaining elements; similarly, if you add another element to the set (e.g. $1 + x + x^2$), you can pretty quickly show that this introduces redundancy and hence linear dependence.

Comment: Thank you but I think I wasnt clear enough in my question. How can you show for an infinite set of vectors that it spans the vector space and thusbis a suitable basis?

Comment: @bananenheld a set of vectors $S$ of a vector space $V$ is spanning provided that for each $v\in V$ there is a finite subset $S'$ of $S$ such that $v=\sum_{s\in S'}c_s s$ for some scalars $c_s$, i.e., "each vector can be expressed as a finite linear combination of vectors from the set."

Comment: Yes but Im talking about an infinite vector space, e.g. L2

Comment: At a high level all such proofs are the same; at a low level, all such proofs depend on the mechanics of the particular vector space involved.  $L_2$ is not just infinite dimensional but of uncountable dimension, you are never going to write down a basis for it explicitly.

Comment: What are you talking about, because $e^{ikx}$ is a basis.

Comment: @bananenheld The set of such exponentials may be a basis for something, but not for anything that is traditionally called $L_2$.

Comment: See e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4669700/1070018